# xcode - How to downgrade xcode 6 storyboard file to xcode 5?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, xcode6

How can I downgrade one of the storyboards that was created in xcode 6 to xcode 5? Note that I am using xcode 5.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must use Xcode 6 to downgrade a storyboard.  If you can't run it, you need to find a friend who can.

Open the storyboard in Xcode 6.  In the File Inspector, find the “Opens In” menu and set it to “Xcode 5.1”.  If the storyboard uses size classes, choose the size class to preserve.  Save the file.

[image: downgrading storyboard]

Comment: Great answer. First time I am seeing animation in stackoverflow.

Comment: That gif is marvelous! How did you do it? I'd love to use this.

Answer (score 1):

Open your storyboard in Xcode. Open the Utilities panel on the right, click on the File Inspector tab, and choose from the Interface Builder Document dropdown.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Already answered before by @Mark Edington

```
Perform these steps to make a storyboard modified by Xcode 6 load and compile again with Xcode 5:

Using Xcode 6:

1. Set the "Opens in" to Xcode 5.1 in the Interface Builder Document Section of the storyboard File Inspector
2. Uncheck the "Use Size Classes"
3. Delete the constraints added using Xcode 6
4. Ensure that the storyboard no longer contains this key at the top of the file:

<capability name="Constraints to layout margins" minToolsVersion="6.0"/>
```

5. Open the project in Xcode 5, recreate the deleted constraints and compile